# What is the relationship between Azure and Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We have a Visual Studio Team Services instance that is used by the company I work for.
The company has an Azure instance.  As far as I am aware there is no connection to VSTS.

When I was added to VSTS as a Visual Studio Pro level user some months ago we had to use my Microsoft Account as we couldn't use my work identity because my MSDN subscription is linked to my Microsoft Account as we could not link it to my work identity; apparently this was because we use Office365 in the office.

We now have problems adding Basic Users to VSTS.  I enter the users Microsoft Account identity and I am told "No Identities Found".

I looked at VSTS Settings where I can see "This account is backed by the Default Directory Azure Active Directory."
I can also see an "Azure Subscription ID".  When I follow the Subscription ID link I end up at my Microsoft Account Azure instance.
I had other users log in to VSTS and they too are seeing my Azure Subscription ID in VSTS Settings.

Why is this happening?
How do Azure instances/accounts relate to VSTS instances/accounts
Can I break the link between Azure and VSTS

Comment: For the issue of "no identities found", do you specify the mail address? What's the result if you add a new registered Microsoft account?

Comment: The "no identities found" message comes when I try to add a recently created Microsoft Account (not mine) to VSTS .   The Account uses a Hotmail account as the identity

Comment: Can you add other account to your VSTS? Try to create a VSTS account with that microsoft account and check the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an idiot.
Turns out the company VSTS *was* linking to the company Azure.

I became confused when clicking the Manage button in VSTS | Azure Subscription ID.
That took me to the Sign in to Azure page and displayed my login, which takes me my Azure.

It was only when we checked the Azure Subscription ID in VSTS against my Azure Subscription ID that it became apparent I was following a red herring.  The ID matched the companies Azure ID. So I can use that to add users and subsequently add them to VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

You can link your VSTS account to the azure from your azure portal:
[Azure - VSTS service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ugmA.png)

Then, what we do is to add the users to the Azure active directories. As far as I know, these users must be registered in Microsoft.

Once it's done, you can add the users to the VSTS.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: The Azure is my personal instance.  I don't really want to be administrating the companies VSTS users from my personal Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

The Team Services uses an [Azure subscription to bill purchases](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/set-up-billing-for-your-account-vs) and [can control access with Azure AD](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/manage-organization-access-for-your-account-vs#disconnect-your-team-services-account-from-azure-ad).

You can unlink your VSTS account from Azure portal. More information, you can refer to this article: [Delete or recover Visual Studio Team Services account](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/delete-or-recover-your-account-vs)